# How to create global attribute in Yii2 application

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using Yii2 and want to create a attribute and access this attribute in every where in my project for exp:

```
Yii::$app->name
```

Above is an example of yii2 default name.
Is there any way to declare my custom attribute as following :

```
Yii::$app->supportname
```

Comment: You should use params ...  `Yii::$app->params['your_param']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend `Application` class, add required properties, and use it on bootstrap.

Create class for web:

```
class MyApplication extends \yii\web\Application {

    public $supportname;
}
```

And use it in `index.php`:

```
(new MyApplication($config))->run();
```

You need to do the same for `\yii\console\Application` and `yii` script.

---

But probably the best way is to use [`Application::$params`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-applications#params) and access value by `Yii::$app->params['supportname']`.

Comment: thanks for your time, I know about setting param but i was curious to know about my query. It seems $params will be best option instead of extending the application.